# How to stop intellisense from auto-completing UNLESS i press space or a specific character to activate it

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm trying to write some code in C# in visual studio after a while working mostly on c++ and the settings for C# are driving me nuts. I hate hate hate auto complete activating at the touch of any number of characters I might type as part of a single line, and I only want it to go off if I specifically intend to activate it. However, I've had no luck preventing it from activating. In particular it's giving me a really hard time with [].

I tried all characters from the "committed by typing the following characters" selection in options, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Please help this is wrecking my work flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2013, I can go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Uncheck "Auto-list members", in order to disable proactive intellisense. I would imagine it is similar for Visual Studio 2012.

You can still manually activate intellisense using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.